# Segmentation fault when using a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, overloading, shared-ptr

I am making a particle system and I'm struggling with how to structure my code. The idea is that a user can create one or several `ParticleEmitter` objects that are passed to a `ParticleManager` object via the `ofxCurlNoise` object.

Now, I want that when the user updates the `ParticleEmitters` objects, the `ParticleManager` object sees the changes made. So I used shared pointers but I have segmentation faults at different times, whether I use one `ParticleEmitter` (segmentation fault when the program starts) or a `vector<ParticleEmitter>` (segmentation fault when the program exits).

What is wrong with this? Is there a design pattern for doing what I'm trying to do?

**ofApp.h**

```
#include "ofxCurlNoise.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

    // ParticleEmitter particleEmitter;
    vector<ParticleEmitter> particleEmitters;
    ofxCurlNoise curlNoise;

    public:
        void setup();

};
```

**ofApp.cpp**

```
#include "ofApp.h"

void ofApp::setup(){
    // This produces a segfault as soon as the program starts
    // particleEmitter.setup();
    // curlNoise.setup(particleEmitter, 1024*256);

    // This produces a segfault when the program exits
    ParticleEmitter emitter;
    emitter.setup();
    particleEmitters.push_back(emitter);
    curlNoise.setup(particleEmitters, 1024*256);    

}
```

**ofxCurlNoise.h**

```
#include "ParticleManager.h"

class ofxCurlNoise {    

    ParticleManager particleManager;

    public:
        void setup(ParticleEmitter& emitter, int n);
        void setup(vector<ParticleEmitter>& emitters, int n);

    private:
        void setup(int n);    

};
```

**ofxCurlNoise.cpp**

```
#include "ofxCurlNoise.h"

void ofxCurlNoise::setup(ParticleEmitter& emitter, int n){
    particleManager.addEmitter(shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(&emitter));
    setup(n);
}

void ofxCurlNoise::setup(vector<ParticleEmitter>& emitters, int n){
    for(auto& e : emitters){
        particleManager.addEmitter(shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(&e));
    }
    setup(n);
}

void ofxCurlNoise::setup(int n){
    particleManager.setup(n);
}
```

**ParticleManager.h**

```
#include "ParticleEmitter.h"

class ParticleManager{    

    vector<shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>> emitters;

    public:
        void addEmitter(const shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>& emitter);
        void setup(int n);
};
```

**ParticleManager.cpp**

```
#include "ParticleManager.h"

void ParticleManager::setup(int n){
    //...
}

void ParticleManager::addEmitter(const shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>& emitter){
    emitters.push_back(emitter);
}
```

Comment: Quoting SO guidelines: "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This one *does* actually contain both the code necessary to identify the error, and a reasonably clear problem statement. It's not a stellar question, but I've seen worse.

Comment: In `std::shared_ptr` you can kept only dynamically created objects (by `new`)... From what  I see - you are passing to `std::shared_ptr` whatever is in `vector<ParticleEmitter>`...

Comment: It doesn't have a `main()`, it has a bunch of different classes and functions, so there are both parts missing and superfluous. This stands in contrast to the quoted rule, @Angew.

Comment: Yes sorry if I wasn't clear enough. It's code for openFrameworks, `ofApp::setup()` is called when the program starts.

Comment: I guessed that already, but there are reasons for those guidelines. If you had taken the time to first reduce the problem, you would have found that the use of openFrameworks is irrelevant. You would then have been able to reduce the problem to something like 20 lines of code, which in turn would have helped *you* focus on the issue. That's a basic problem solving strategy which you should learn. It also makes this post clearer and more useful for others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not how `std::shared_ptr` works. You are creating your instances of `ParticleEmitter` on the stack, but `std::shared_ptr` is used to manage instances which are created on the heap. In your code, when you add a new emitter to the `ParticleManager`, and wrap it into a shared pointer, the emitter is destroyed when the `particleEmitters` vector is destroyed (when, in turn, your `ofApp` instance is destroyed) and is thus destroyed regardless.

When the instance of `ofApp` is destroyed, both the instance of `ofxCurlNoise` and `particleEmitters` are destroyed (in that order). So ofxCurlNoise will in turn destroy the `particleManager`, which manages your shared pointers, which will then delete your particle emitters (which were originally created on the stack). After all that is done, the `particleEmitters` vector is getting destroyed, and the runtime system will try to destroy your particle emitters again, leading to the error you are seeing.

Furthermore, shared pointers are used to model shared ownership semantics, which I don't see in your use case. I think you'd be better off to either use `std::unique_ptr` to manage instances created on the heap, or to not use smart pointers at all and create everything on the stack (which you are almost doing already).

Comment: +1, with a minor nitpick: the OP is pointing the `shared_ptr`s at elements in a `vector`, not at local variables.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So shared_ptr are not the right tool to do it. But the thing is that I'd like not to use pointers to `ParticleEmitters` objects in the `ofApp` class. However, the changes made to a `ParticleEmitter` in `ofApp` have to be seen in `ParticleManager`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ElieGnrd First you need to clarify the ownership semantics. Who owns the particle emitters, i.e., who should be responsible for managing their lifecycle?

Comment: `ofApp` owns the `ParticleEmitter`s

Comment: You can create your emitters on the heap and store them in a vector of std::unique_ptrs in ofApp. Then you can either pass the instances as raw pointers, or you can pass a reference to the vector. Or you can create them on the stack and have them managed by the vector, and pass a reference to the vector.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to be used by other users (it's an addon for a framework). The users will only write code in the `ofApp` class, and I want it to be as simple as possible (i.e. not using pointers in ofApp). So is there a way to do this and keeping the code in `ofApp` as it is?

Comment: Yes, pass your vector of emitters by reference to the constructor of ParticleManager and store the reference there. But you have to make damn sure that ParticleManager is destroyed before ofApp is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71475/discussion-between-elie-gnrd-and-kristian-duske).

Answer (score 2):

You should never create shared_ptr from an ordinary pointer as you do here:

```
 shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(&e)
```

This tries to free the ParticleEmitter twice. Once as the vector holding the ParticleEmitter objects goes out of scope, and once as the shared_ptr goes out of scope.

Comment: A built-in pointer e.g. ParticleEmitter*, not a smart-pointer.

Comment: Then you need an ordinary pointer when creating a shared_ptr, there is no other way to use it

Comment: Best practise is to use make_shared() to create the shared_ptr. But you are right, I could have been more precise about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ofxCurlNoise::setup(vector<ParticleEmitter>& emitters, int n){
   for(auto& e : emitters){
    particleManager.addEmitter(shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(&e));
  }
  setup(n);
}
```

Looks like you are making shared pointer from "stack" allocated objects.You should construct `ParticleEmitter` objects using `new` or `make_shared<ParticleEmitter>`, but what happens is that when vector is resized and `ParticleEmitter` is copied on new location `shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>` points to wrong address. Additionaly when vector gets out of scoped elemnts get destructed .

Comment: `e` is not a stack object, it is a reference to an object managed by a std::vector

Comment: It is not on stack, but looks like it is. On top of destruction controlled by vector it is also moved on another memory location, when size of  vector changes.

Answer (score 0):

When passing a pointer to a `shared_ptr`, the latter takes ownership of it and manages it. As you pass a pointer to an object already managed by a std::vector, it will be deleted twice sooner or later, which cannot work of course. `shared_ptr` must be passed a pointer which is not already managed by another class.

So instead of:

```
shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(&e)
```

You must create a copy of the `ParticleEmitter` object

Use:

```
shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(new ParticleEmitter(e))
```

Or better:

```
std::make_shared<ParticleEmitter>(e)
```

Both methods require `ParticleEmitter` to have a copy constructor.

If the `ParticleEmitter` is a heavy class and you want to avoid making a deep-copy of it, then it must implement move semantics (move constructor) and use:

```
std::make_shared<ParticleEmitter>(std::move(e))
```